# Unable to create table sqlite table in xamarin(Device only) Emulator works fine

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using SQLite-net-PCL nugget I'm unable to create a table with this model. I'm getting this exception here.

Inner Exception condition:

```
  at SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare2 (SQLitePCL.sqlite3 db, System.String query) [0x0001b] in <eaa146ee868043e287f5507c8701ad9e>:0 
02-01 18:18:23.620 I/mono-stdout( 3072):   at SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare2 (SQLitePCL.sqlite3 db, System.String query) [0x0001b] in <eaa146ee868043e287f5507c8701ad9e>:0 
  at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.Prepare () [0x00011] in <eaa146ee868043e287f5507c8701ad9e>:0 
02-01 18:18:23.625 I/mono-stdout( 3072):   at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.Prepare () [0x00011] in <eaa146ee868043e287f5507c8701ad9e>:0 
  at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery () [0x00030] in <eaa146ee868043e287f5507c8701ad9e>:0 
02-01 18:18:23.627 I/mono-stdout( 3072):   at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery () [0x00030] in <eaa146ee868043e287f5507c8701ad9e>:0 
  at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Execute (System.String query, System.Object[] args) [0x00039] in <eaa146ee868043e287f5507c8701ad9e>:0 
02-01 18:18:23.629 I/mono-stdout( 3072):   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Execute (System.String query, System.Object[] args) [0x00039] in <eaa146ee868043e287f5507c8701ad9e>:0 
  at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.MigrateTable (SQLite.TableMapping map, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] existingCols) [0x000ae] in <eaa146ee868043e287f5507c8701ad9e>:0 
02-01 18:18:23.631 I/mono-stdout( 3072):   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.MigrateTable (SQLite.TableMapping map, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] existingCols) [0x000ae] in <eaa146ee868043e287f5507c8701ad9e>:0 
  at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateTable (System.Type ty, SQLite.CreateFlags createFlags) [0x0013e] in <eaa146ee868043e287f5507c8701ad9e>:0 
02-01 18:18:23.632 I/mono-stdout( 3072):   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateTable (System.Type ty, SQLite.CreateFlags createFlags) [0x0013e] in <eaa146ee868043e287f5507c8701ad9e>:0 
  at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateTable[T] (SQLite.CreateFlags createFlags) [0x00000] in <eaa146ee868043e287f5507c8701ad9e>:0 
02-01 18:18:23.634 I/mono-stdout( 3072):   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateTable[T] (SQLite.CreateFlags createFlags) [0x00000] in <eaa146ee868043e287f5507c8701ad9e>:0 
  at SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection+<>c__DisplayClass31_0`1[T].<CreateTableAsync>b__0 (SQLite.SQLiteConnectionWithLock conn) [0x00000] in <eaa146ee868043e287f5507c8701ad9e>:0 
02-01 18:18:23.636 I/mono-stdout( 3072):   at SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection+<>c__DisplayClass31_0`1[T].<CreateTableAsync>b__0 (SQLite.SQLiteConnectionWithLock conn) [0x00000] in <eaa146ee868043e287f5507c8701ad9e>:0 
  at SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection+<>c__DisplayClass29_0`1[T].<WriteAsync>b__0 () [0x00013] in <eaa146ee868043e287f5507c8701ad9e>:0 
02-01 18:18:23.638 I/mono-stdout( 3072):   at SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection+<>c__DisplayClass29_0`1[T].<WriteAsync>b__0 () [0x00013] in <eaa146ee868043e287f5507c8701ad9e>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
02-01 18:18:23.640 I/mono-stdout( 3072):   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 02-01 18:18:23.641 I/mono-
```

---

```
public class Setting
{
    [PrimaryKey]
   //  public int id { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool AutoUpload { get; set; }
    public bool UseCellularData { get; set; }
    public int MaxStoredRecordings { get; set; }
    public string UnitPreference { get; set; }
    public string DateFormatPreference { get; set; }
    public string TimeFormat { get; set; }
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }
}
```

Actual exception:

I'm getting this exception

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler(  487): CM callback handler got msg 524294
02-01 19:06:50.907 I/mono-stdout(  487):   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00043] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 02-01 19:06:50.917 I/mono-stdout(  487):   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00043] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () [0x00000] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
02-01 19:06:50.919 I/mono-stdout(  487):   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () [0x00000] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
  at Feelix.Storage.DatabaseManager..ctor (System.String dbPath) [0x0003c] in D:\22\developer branch\Feelix\Feelix\Feelix\Storage\DatabaseManager.cs:45 
02-01 19:06:50.921 I/mono-stdout(  487):   at Feelix.Storage.DatabaseManager..ctor (System.String dbPath) [0x0003c] in D:\22\developer branch\Feelix\Feelix\Feelix\Storage\DatabaseManager.cs:45 
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #2
The thread 0x2 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

My table

```
 database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
            database.CreateTableAsync<Patient>().Wait();
            database.CreateTableAsync<User>().Wait()
            database.CreateTableAsync<Setting>().Wait();
            database.CreateTableAsync<DeviceSessionDB>().Wait();
            database.CreateTableAsync<DeviceSessionRecordingsDB>().Wait();
```

All tables are created successfully except setting page table.

Comment: Are you trying to alter an existing table?

Comment: Can you show the actual exception message and the code?

Comment: No Im not altering this table @SushiHangover

Comment: Hi @Crowcoder, I'm getting this exception

Comment: In your `catch` block [flatten the aggregate exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception.flatten?view=netframework-4.7.2) and update the question with the exception message.

Comment: Hi @Crowcoder,Please see the updated data above,Thanks,Suriya

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will fix it, but I use an async method to create the tables instead of `Wait()`. Below is how I do it, using your code (I removed the async lock code to make it more simple):

```
public class Repo {
    //set up 'database' variable

    public Repo() {
        CreateTablesAsync()
    }

    private async void CreateTablesAsync() {
        await database.CreateTableAsync<Patient>().ConfigureAwait(false);
        await database.CreateTableAsync<User>().ConfigureAwait(false);
        await database.CreateTableAsync<Setting>().ConfigureAwait(false);
        await database.CreateTableAsync<DeviceSessionDB>().ConfigureAwait(false);
        await database.CreateTableAsync<DeviceSessionRecordingsDB>().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Wait() on this async call, It creates some sort of a deadlock you simply need to do this:

```
 database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
 database.CreateTableAsync<Patient>();
 database.CreateTableAsync<User>();
 database.CreateTableAsync<Setting>();
 database.CreateTableAsync<DeviceSessionDB>();
 database.CreateTableAsync<DeviceSessionRecordingsDB>();
```